# How do I fix this Query in my Google Document?

Tags: google-docs

Could not really find much on this issue, and I even had my father, who works with excel all the time, walk away stumped on this one. Hoping you guys could shed some light!

Here is a copy of the document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dH86E1hZRQMj3UL6n4B81IVEkHS5_djkXhHkOl3LOSE/edit?usp=sharing

So this was made for my Runescape clan for us to determine when users require a promotion; it simply makes things easier for us. I'm pulling the data with IMPORTHTML from a site that already tracks the data, my document just arranges it for our personal use (promotions).

On the right should be a list of just people that need the promotion, however, it seems whoever is first on the column I select with the QUERY (A2:D501, Pea being A2), they get put there regardless if they meet the criteria. In this case, under "General Promotions", they need a Clan XP of 250,000,000 and they must be a Captain rank (it goes Captain -> General), yet the Owner (both under 250m exp and not a Captain), is showing up there and under all categories.

Have no idea why this is happening, so if anyone could enlighten me, I would be greatly appreciative!

All I want is if there are no users who fit the criteria, I can have it say something like "No Promotions Yet". Couldn't figure that one out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this formula work as you want in cell F3:

`=IFERROR(QUERY(A2:D501, "select A,B,D where D >= 250000000 and B contains 'Captain'"),"No Promotions Yet")`

You will need to delete the formula you have in columns G & H though - QUERY can output multiple columns rather than needing a separate formula for each one.

Comment: Yes! This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Was not aware QUERY could output for multiple columns.